# Objective C- how to upload a file from iphone by giving its path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cordova, dropbox-api

My code to upload a file from my app to dropbox using dropbox plugin.The code below works in simulator but when i run it the path will be different.How can i access the iphone path?

```
-(void) upload:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;

NSString* javaScript = nil;

NSLog(@"Dropbox backup method is executing");

NSString *str=[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"file:%@",str);

NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *destDir = @"/";

[[self restClient] uploadFile:str toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:    

[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:str]];

pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];

javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:command.callbackId];

[self writeJavascript:javaScript];
}
```

Anybody can please tell me how to access the path of iphone?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *yourPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"%@",str];
```

Comment: It works!!! but i need the app folder and from it i need to get the file to download,this code takes the files from the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *bundle=[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];

Using this code we can get the path of the files in the device.